# Date calculations by quarter-year

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, date

I am looking for a simple but efficient Objective-C algorithm which, starting from a given quarter of a year (3 months), adds or subtracts a specific number of quarters.

For example, adding 10 quarters to Q1 of 2012, I get the year: 2012 + Floor(10 / 4) = 2012 + 2 = 2014, then the quarter: 1 + Mod (10, 4) = 1 + 2 = Q3. Subtracting 2 quarters from Q3 of 2011, I want to end up with Q1 of 2011.

What would be the most elegant code to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you starting with a specific date, or how is your data stored?  If it is a specific date, do you want the beginning of the quarter that you calculate, or simply add three month periods to the date that you start with?

Comment: The date is stored as two int's (one for the quarter, 1..4) and one for the year (2000..2012). This is how I started, but my algorithm is not yet finished: `const int periodsInYear = 4; //4 quarters in a year`
    `int yearsToAdd = floor(periodsToAdd / periodsInYear); //take only the integer part of the result, i.e. 10 quarters / 4 = 2.5, floor = 2`
    `int periodsInYearToAdd = fmod(periodsToAdd, periodsInYear); // i.e. 10 quarters, 10 mod 4 = 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)addQuarters:(NSInteger)quarters toYear:(NSInteger *)currentYear andQuarter:(NSInteger *)currentQuarter {
    if (*currentYear < 0 ||
        *currentQuarter < 1 ||
        *currentQuarter > 4) {
        return;
    }

    *currentYear += quarters / 4;
    *currentQuarter += quarters % 4;

    if (*currentQuarter  > 4) {
        *currentQuarter -= 4;
        *currentYear += 1;
    } else if (*currentQuarter < 1) {
        *currentQuarter += 4;
        *currentYear -= 1;
    }
}

// Example of use:
NSInteger year = 2012;
NSInteger quarter = 2;

[self addQuarters:-7 toYear:&year andQuarter:&quarter];
NSLog(@"Quarter %i of %i", quarter, year);
// Output: Quarter 3 of 2010
```

Comment: Note that floor isn't needed because in C (and Objective-C) integer division always truncates the remainder (rounds down).

Answer (score 3):

Code altered from here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
          initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[offsetComponents setMonth:3]; // one quarter

NSDate *oneQuarterFromToday = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents
          toDate:today options:0];
```

Comment: Might be worth using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` rather than the generic `NSGregorianCalendar` on the basis that calendars have a time zone and exactly how far away three months is may depend on whether your region observes daylight savings? I'm probably being overly sensitive.

Comment: This will not work because today can be between quarters. You can't just add 3 months to arbitrary month in in the year and expect it to be a quarter.